# Returning arrays and looping

Tags: java, arrays, methods

I am new to Java and am assigned to design a program that grabs input from a file and inserts it to certain parts of an array, then exports that data. I have the code to read the file into a string array.

Two questions:

1.) How can I create a loop to create a numbered list with blank data following it? (see my code snippet below) I am trying to create a list that looks like the following:

```
1 0000 0000 00000 ...
2 0000 0000 00000 ...
```

Do you see any issues with my loop below?

```
for (int x = 0; x < array.length; x++) {
        array[x] = Integer.toString(y);
        y++;
            while (x < 16) {
            x++;
            array[x] = "00000";
            }
    }
```

2.) Can I use a single method to return two array values? I would like two arrays filled, then their values returned for use in other methods. I found a method I could use, but I'm not sure how to go about properly implementing it.
I have a code snippet below:

```
    public static Object[] rtrStr() {
    //...blah blah
    return new Object[]{array1, array2};}
```

Comment: Does your loop do what you expect?

Comment: for question1, what is y? and what is the magic number 16? for question2, you have many ways to do it. array[][], List, Map

Comment: I wanted a single loop to do what the list looks like above. I put in the y variable as an attempt to keep the array indexes in order, but I'm not getting what I want from it.

Answer (score 0):

2) You can return an array (or `List`) of arrays, if you wish:

```
public static String[][] rtrStr() {
    // ...blah blah
    String[][] arr = new String[][2]; // syntax might not be exactly correct

    arr[0] = array1;
    arr[1] = array2;
}
```

**Note:** I'm unsure about the exact syntax on the noted line, but the idea is sound. Personally, I would prefer using a `List` instead.

With that said, you should consider the meaning of the data in each array. It might make sense to create a custom class which wraps the array and clarifies the semantics. This also makes it easier to return an array or List from any method since the elements will be objects of your new custom class.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you see any issues with my loop below?

Yes, multiple: Your code is what I would call bad code. Even if it does what you want (and I'm not sure of that), it's extremely difficult to understand for such a simple task.

1. You're using `x` and `y` as counter-variable names. Don't do that when more than one counter is involved! It's hard to understand exactly what counter is counting what.
2. Your inner loop is messing with the counter-variable of your outer loop. If that was by design, don't **ever** do this. It makes the code very difficult to understand.

Also, if the array should hold something like a table (rows and columns) like in your example output, you'll need a two-dimensional array.

---

> Can I use a single method to return two array values?

Yes, why not? You're actually returning **one** array with **two** values. You can however **not** return **two arrays** from a single method.